# I cant get my code to output to my text file

Tags: c++

I cant get code to output to file KirklandLabResults.txt

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream input;
    ofstream output;
    string fName, lName;
    double loanAmount, numberOfPayments;
    double interestRate = 0;
    double monthlyPayment = 0;
    double totalPayed = 0;
    double interestAmount = 0;
    input.open("Lab4Data.txt");
    output.open("Kirklandlab4results.txt"); //numberOfPayments = numberOfPayments * 12;         //monthlyPayment = loanAmount * interestRate*pow(loanAmount+interestRate, numberOfPayments)/pow(loanAmount+interestRate,numberOfPayments)-1;    //totalPayed = monthlyPayment * numberOfPayments;   //interestAmount = interestRate * numberOfPayments;         //input.open("Lab4Data.txt");   //output.open("Kirklandlab4results.txt");

    input >> fName >> lName;
    output << "Name:" << fName << " " << lName << endl;

    input >> loanAmount;
    output << "Loan Amount:" << loanAmount << endl;

    input >> interestRate;
    output << "Monthly Intrest Rate:" << interestRate << endl;
    interestRate = interestRate / 12;
    interestRate
        = interestRate / 100;

    input >> numberOfPayments;
    output << "Number Of Payments:" << numberOfPayments << endl;
    numberOfPayments = numberOfPayments * 12;

    output << "Monthly Payment:" << monthlyPayment << endl;
    monthlyPayment = loanAmount * interestRate * pow(loanAmount + interestRate, numberOfPayments) / pow(loanAmount + interestRate, numberOfPayments) - 1;
    output << "Total Amount Payed:" << totalPayed << endl;
    totalPayed = monthlyPayment * numberOfPayments;
    output << "Interest Amount:" << interestAmount << endl;
    interestAmount = interestRate * numberOfPayments;

    input.close();
    output.close();

    return 0;
```

Comment: It should output to a file. It may be the wrong values. You added this `interestAmount = interestRate * numberOfPayments;` statement after you printed the calculation so it has no function. You seem to be doing your calculations after you print. Remember that `c++` will execute your code in the order you have it.

Comment: @drescherjm I put the calculations in the right order but its still not working, It wont even print fName and lName.

Comment: Maybe you should verify that the open of the output file was a success. Your code blindly assumes that both files are opened successfully and that the input file has the correct contents. Both of these could be incorrect.

Comment: @drescherjm How would I go about doing that, sorry I just got into coding

Comment: Recommendation: Test everything you can so you know if something went wrong. If you don't, then what could have been a trivial mistake becomes a surprise debugging  session. If `input >> loanAmount;` is changed to `If (input >> loanAmount) { /* do stuff with loanAmount */ } else { /* handle error */}` you'll have fewer worries. Do not be surprised if your code sometimes winds up looking like 10% algorithm and 90% error checking. It's a cost of business, and it saves you time in the long run.

Comment: @drescherjm `ofstream::open()` has a `void` return type. Use `ofstream::is_open()` instead: `output.open("Kirklandlab4results.txt"); if (!output.is_open()) { std::cout << "Could not open the output file. The program will end." << std::endl; return -1; }`